# CASE BETWEEN Statement

Tags: php, mariadb

I have a simple log table in my database. For each page visit a row is inserted. Now i want to sum up a certain column for today and yesterday.

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT Sum(CASE 
             WHEN `time` > 1364767200 THEN `sqlquerycount` 
           end) AS `today`, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN `time` BETWEEN 1364684400 AND 1364767200 THEN `sqlquerycount` 
           end) AS `yesterday` 
FROM   `log`
```

which results of the following PHP script:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN `time` > ".strtotime("today")." THEN `sqlQueryCount` END) AS `today`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `time` BETWEEN ".strtotime("yesterday")." AND ".strtotime("today")." THEN `sqlQueryCount` END) AS `yesterday`
    FROM `log`";
```

"yesterday" is remaining NULL, but I don't see any problem with this query. Any idea?

Comment: Are you using `mariadb` or `mysql`?

Comment: What's the result of `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log WHERE time BETWEEN 1364684400 AND 1364767200`?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I had thought there was something like a 30day minimum waiting period on username changes, but lately you seem to have disproved that.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO the result is 0.

Comment: isn't is simpler to group by floor(time/86400) and aggregate?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Create a new account on a SE site and propagate :)

Comment: @BananaBoss Then that's why you're getting `NULL`. Were you expecting `0` as a result?

Comment: So, do I get that right? He does not have any rows matching this condition and is returning NULL because of that?

Comment: @BananaBoss The `SUM` of no rows is `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd bet for

```
$sql = "SELECT 
        SUM(CASE WHEN `time` > ".strtotime("today")." THEN `sqlQueryCount` ELSE 0 END) AS `today`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `time` BETWEEN ".strtotime("yesterday")." AND ".strtotime("today")." THEN `sqlQueryCount` ELSE 0 END) AS `yesterday`
    FROM `log`";
```

... provided `sqlQueryCount` is the the column you want to do the sum on!

Comment: I'm upvoting this because OP likely wants to see a numeric result.

Comment: +1. In addition to the comments at my question, this seems to be a solution. Thank you!